# tensorflow GPU: resource exhausted error

Tags: nvidia, tensorflow

I'm currently running a CNN on 3D medical images on tensorflow GPU. Whenever I run the code, resource exhausted error appears on the command prompt. I have already tried running the code in  small batches of size 1(one patient at a time).

My GPU is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960. I'm looking at my GPU's specifications, but I'm not sure which component is limiting the memory. Is it the Standard Memory Config(2GB)?

The command prompt returns the following:

2017-06-11 16:23:37.095587: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1152] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[3,3,3,8,16]
2017-06-11 16:23:47.096178: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:273] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 365.63MiB.

Current allocation summary follows.
2017-06-11 16:23:47.096349: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:643] Bin (256):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0 0B allocated for chunks. 0B client-requested for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
......
2017-06-11 16:23:47.144036: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:696] 3 Chunks of size 13824 totalling 40.5KiB
2017-06-11 16:23:47.144745: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:696] 3 Chunks of size 383385600 totalling 1.07GiB
2017-06-11 16:23:47.145486: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:696] 1 Chunks of size 398141184 totalling 379.70MiB
2017-06-11 16:23:47.146771: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:700] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 1.44GiB
2017-06-11 16:23:47.146796: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:702]

Stats:

Limit:                  1548396134

InUse:                  1548374272

MaxInUse:               1548396032

NumAllocs:                      35

MaxAllocSize:            398141184

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue. Have you found any solution, if yes, could you please do direct me to it?